# Why does allah swt say he made prophet muhammad a.s indepedent even though prophet muhammad a.s still needs him

Tags: allah, prophet-muhammad, contradiction

In this verse it says [(Ad-Duha 93:1–11)](https://quran.com/ad-duhaa) Prophet muhammad Pbuh still needs Allah swt but why did allah swt say he made him indepedent?

Answer (score 0):

One of Allah's name is المغنىّ Al-Mughni - The One Who provides all that is needed.

Here in this verse the meaning is

> And did He not find you needy then satisfied your needs?

So it is Allah who satisfied his needs.